# Synonym for competitive that has negative connotations

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective or a noun or a verb that means to be overly competitive in a way that makes you lose sight of how you're affecting others around you.

Example. "Ben was (behaving) **** , working on his . He was laser-focused on his project at the expense of spending time with his family.

Comment: _Competitive_ has negative connotations already.

Comment: Ben was behaving like a *workaholic cornered rat*.

Comment: 'Competitive' is an adjective, which doesn't fit in your sample sentence. 'Cutthroat' is given at the duplicate mentioned; 'dog-eat-dog'  and 'ruthless' are readily found by looking for synonyms.